# Односвязный список, конструктор

Tags: c++, list

Нужно создать список, и провести некоторые работы, но не получается вызвать конструктор, не могу понять, как сделать. Строка ниже отмечена комментарием.

```
    class Students {
public:
    Students();
    ~Students();
    void push_back(int marks[8], char name[20], int volume);


private:
    class Node {
        Node* pNext;
        char name[20];
        int marks[8]; // Оценки
        int volume; // стипендия
        Node(int marks[8], char name[20], int volume, Node* pNext = nullptr) {
            this->marks[8] = marks[8];
            this->pNext = pNext;
            this->name[20] = name[20];
            this->volume = volume;
        }
    };
    int Size;
    Node* head;
};

Students::Students() {
    Size = 0;
    head = nullptr;
}

Students::~Students() {

}

void Students::push_back(int marks[8], char name[20], int volume) {
    if (head = nullptr) {
        head = new Node(marks[8], name[20], volume); // Выдает ошибку отсутствует экземпляр конструктора
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Comment: @Harry, Опечатался, видимо, когда пробовал исправить, в итоге, на автомате записал переменные

Comment: вы пытаетесь передавать элемент массива, а конструктор принимает указатель.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C++ нельзя передавать массивы фиксированного размера по значению.  Можно передавать по указателю (и копировать вручную), можно по ссылке `int (&marks)[8]`, можно через `std::array`: `std::aray<int, 8> marks`. В нормальном C++ более-менее корректный вариант выглядел бы так:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>
class Students{
   struct Node{
      std::string name;
      std::array<int, 8> works;
      int volume;
      Node* next;
   };

    size_t size = 0;
    Node* head = nullptr;

public:
    // Конструктор по умолчанию инициализирует нулями, т.к. заданы значения по умолчанию
    Students() = default;

    // works тут можно передавать и по ссылке, но для малых массивов (примерно до 10 машинных слов) смысла добавлять дополнительную косвенность нет.
    void push_back(const std::string& name, std::array<int, 8> works, int volume){
        if (head == nullptr) {
            // Конструктор для чистых структур генерируется автоматически
            head = new Node{name, works, volume, nullptr}; 
            size = 1;
        } else{
           // ....
        }
    }
};
```

С инкапсуляцией тут проблем нет, т.к. `Node`  - приватная структура.

Если вам нельзя использовать библиотечные классы - передавайте как `int (&marks)[8]` или `const int* marks`, но не забудьте, что нужно копировать данные, а не указатели.